# How to position div placed inside iFrame in centre of the screen

Tags: html, css, iframe, layout, css-position

I have a div that is placed inside iFrame. Now this iFrame is position right on the screeen.

Now I am in need to position a div that is inside this frame relative to window not to its container.

html

```
 <FRAMESET rows="136,*" frameborder="no" framespacing="0">
    <FRAME id="cmTop" scrolling="no" src="ABC.aspx?empNo=<%=strEncrEmpNo%>" noresize>
</FRAMESET>
```

ABC.aspx

```
<div id="popUp"> 
 This is popUp div that I need to place right on the middle of the screen 
</div>
```

I tried with the position: fixed, static,absolute but somehow the div is not coming out of the frame.

```
div#popUp 
{
  positon:fixed;
  top:25px;
  left : 20%;
  z-index : 999999999;
}
```

The reason for this structure is this is a legacy system and I have no control to remove these frames.

Comment: So, you want to position the div in a place, which is not in the frame, which the div is in? That is like wanting to take out the egg yolk from an egg without breaking it's shell.
What I mean is, I don't think that is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there a clean way to do what you want,
I can give some tips but not a solution, hopefully someone will give you a work round. 
you could try to append your popup to the parent of the IFRAME by 
window.parent.appendChild() or window.parent.querySelector('#myDivPopup').innerHTML = myPopupInsideIframe
BUT HONESTLY THIS A DIRTY WAY.

The best way to communicate between IFRAME and PARENT is window.postmessage(...).

[here an example](http://blog.mandarbadve.com/2013/12/27/call-function-parent-window-iframe-window-javascript/)